# array_reverse как использовать

Tags: php

array_reverse как использовать в данном примере

```
$qm = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT ....");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qm)) {
...
```

это бред:

```
$qm = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT ....");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(array_reverse($qm))) {
...
```

поможете?

Comment: `while($row = array_reverse(mysqli_fetch_array($qm)))`  местами поменяйте.

Comment: Зачем вам `array_reverse`? Порядок строк поменять? Или порядок полей?

Comment: А может проще в select указать поля в правильном порядке ? Если какие то поля из таблиц вам не нужны, то вообще не выбирайте их.

Comment: @Mike Вот я и хочу от автора добиться понимания, зачем ему _тут_ `array_reverse`. Есть у меня подозрение, что ему нужно `ORDER BY ... DESC`

Comment: @tutankhamun Кстати, как вариант :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30) AS td ORDER BY td.id ASC